# Sitecore Publishing Service nuget packages

Tags: publishing-service, nuget

I am trying to use nuget package to install this dll "Sitecore.Publishing.Service.dll" but it seems that it is not there , any one know what is the nuget package for Sitecore Publishing Service dlls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all modules are available (yet) in the Sitecore Nuget feed. SXA for example is not there yet, and it seems like the Publishing service is also (still) missing.

For the moment, you'll need to refer your solution to the dll locally. You can always contact Sitecore (through [support](https://support.sitecore.net/helpdesk/) / [uservoice](https://sitecore.uservoice.com/) / ... ) requesting to get the Publishing service module in Nuget as well. For SXA this has been done and the team is working on it (or at least thinking about it).

Comment: Thanks , i will add them to my solution locally

Comment: Please make a support request too to make Sitecore add it. We would like it too!

Comment: When you contact the support with a request you may use the same request number: "I registered the appropriate wish to add the Publishing Service to the NuGet feed. To track the future status of this wish, please use the reference number 288832."

Answer (score 0):

SXA 4.8.0, JSS 12.0.0 and DataExchange 2.1.0 are available on MyGet for Sitecore 9.1.0 release: https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-packages

Also SIF (https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-powershell/package/nuget/SitecoreInstallFramework) and SI (https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-identity) were published on MyGet as part of Sitecore 9.1.0 release.